# SwiftUI: Why UIHostingController(rootView:) can pass nil value?

Tags: swiftui

In Xcode playground :

```
func makeView<T:View>(v: T) -> T?{
    nil
}


let v0 = makeView(v: Text(""))
let view = UIHostingController(rootView: v0)
```

note that func UIHostingController(rootView: ) signature not allowed pass nil value:

```
open class UIHostingController<Content> : UIViewController where Content : View {

    public init(rootView: Content)
}
```

So why I can pass nil to UIHostingController(rootView:) ???

thanks ;)

Update:

So I try to write some one like class UIHostingController：

```
protocol P{
    var name: String {get}
}

class Container<T> where T: P{
    init(a:T){
        print(a.name)
    }
}

struct A: P {
    var name:String
    
    init?(name:String) {
        
        if name.isEmpty{
            return nil
        }
        
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

but when I create a instance of Container, some wrong happens:

```
let p = Container(a: A(name: ""))
```

compiler complain me ：

> Argument type 'A?' does not conform to expected type 'P'

So how UIHostingController did that???

Answer (score 0):

In the below code, it's true that V0 is nil. But, it's important to note that v0 is of type Text?.

```
let view = UIHostingController(rootView: v0)
```

Even though below line doesn't work

```
let view = UIHostingController(rootView: nil)
```

This works.

```
let view = UIHostingController<Text?>(rootView: nil)
```

To fix the error "Generic class 'Container' requires that 'A?' conform to 'P'", Container class can be updated as below

```
class Container<T>: X where T: P{
    init(a:T?){
        if let a = a {
            print(a.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! but why UIHostingController(rootView:) can pass Optional<View> ???

Comment: Added the updated implementation of initializer. UIHostingController might be doing something similar.